# How to add CSS or styled-components to Link tag in Next.js?

Tags: css, next.js, hyperlink, styled-components, next-link

Cannot add styles in any way to next.js `<Link>` tag.

code:

```
import Link from "next/link";
import styles from "../Components.module.css";

export default function SubjectBTN({ lable, path }) {
  return (
    <Link href={path} className={styles.SubjectBTN}>
        <div>{lable}</div>
    </Link>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was simple, wrap all the components inside the `<Link>` tag with an `<a>` tag, plus add a `passHref` to the Link tag since it passes the href from the Link tag to the a tag otherwise, if you didn't add a passHref, sometimes it will show a `<div>` wrapping the component instead of an  tag and this will result in poor SEO. The code should look as following:

```
import Link from "next/link";
import styles from "../Components.module.css";

export default function SubjectBTN({ lable, path }) {
  return (
    <Link href={path} passHref>
      <a className={styles.SubjectBTN}>
        <div>{lable}</div>
      </a>
    </Link>
  );
}
```

more information can be found [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-custom-component-that-wraps-an-a-tag).